# background image doesn't show

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="home">
<div class="landing-text">
  <h1 class="display-2"> One Piece MMO</h1>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Watch Trailer</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Download Game</button>
</div>
</div>

#home{
background: url(images/bg.png) no-repeat fixed center; 
display: table;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
background-size: cover; 
}
```

why i can't see the background image? can't figure out the problem....tried "background-image: url("image/bg.png") and "background: url("images/bg.png")

Comment: Please create a working example in codepen.io or jsfiddle

Comment: Check the network panel in the inspector in your browser to see what path the browser is trying to load the image from.

Be aware that the image path is relative to the css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your CSS code is inline with the HTML, make sure it's enclosed in `<style>` tags:

```
<div id="home">
<div class="landing-text">
  <h1 class="display-2"> One Piece MMO</h1>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Watch Trailer</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Download Game</button>
</div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
#home {
  background: url(images/bg.png) no-repeat fixed center; 
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover; 
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually correct, which leads me to believe it could have something to do with the path to the image you want to display. I changed the url to a universal one leading to random cat image and it worked. That or enclose your image path between quotes, as in **url("images/bg.png")**.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mg4ht074/)

Check your image path!

```
<div id="home">
<div class="landing-text">
  <h1 class="display-2"> One Piece MMO</h1>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Watch Trailer</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Download Game</button>
</div>
</div>
#home {
background: url(http://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/google-cat-search-2014-_0.jpg) no-repeat fixed center; 
display: table;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
background-size: cover; 
}
```

Comment: thanks, i just have to write full path

Answer (score 0):

You can run it.

```html
<div id="home">
<div class="landing-text">
  <h1 class="display-2"> One Piece MMO</h1>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Watch Trailer</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Download Game</button>
</div>
</div>
<style>
#home {
background: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/happy-childrens-day-design_23-2147705019.jpg) no-repeat fixed center; 
display: table;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
background-size: cover; 
}
<style>
```